# How to get access to TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, classloader

I am connecting to a very old EJB2.1 application from like 2006 with a jar client. I have build a spring boot 2 application that uses this jar client and calls its façade methods. I am experiencing very weird behavior when one method call of the client works fine and another fails on `java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00`. I have found that one works because it is executed from a controller (not directly) and a 2nd one because it is invoked through a JMS message. Now the JMS message invocation runs (the thread) with a context classloader `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`, when the MVC runs with `TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader` (which has a parent `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`). Since this is a wrapper for a very old client, I was thinking I can just swap classloaders in the JMS invocation.

But (THIS IS THE ACTUAL QUESTION) Is there a way to get access to my application `TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader` during spring context initialization so I could set it form my JMS call as well?